# error with pyttsx code from their website

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run this code that is straight from the website

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Greetings!')
engine.say('How are you today?')
engine.runAndWait()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/pyttsx.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx
  File "C:/Python27\pyttsx.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I am on Windows 7 using Python 2.7 and I used *easy_install* to install it. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has name `pyttsx.py`, so you `import` your own file, instead of installed module.

Rename your file.